# Inject multiple classes that use the fetch HttpClient in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, ecmascript-6, aurelia

I have a class called Infrastructure for which I thought it would be handy to inherit from `HttpClient`. This class exposes methods for get, post, put and delete.

```js
import {Aurelia} from "aurelia-framework";
import {HttpClient, json} from "aurelia-fetch-client";

export default class Infrastructure extends HttpClient {
    get(url, queryString, contentType) {
        //..
    }

    post(url, data, contentType) {
        //..
    }

    put(url, data, contentType) {
        //..
    }

    delete(url, contentType) {
        //..
    }
}
```

The idea is that I now can have services that inject `Infrastructure` and they can call `configure` on infrastructure

```js
import {inject} from "aurelia-framework";
import Infrastructure from "./infrastructure";

@inject(Infrastructure)
export class InventoryService {
    constructor (infrastructure) {

        infrastructure.configure(config => {
            config
                .useStandardConfiguration()
                .withBaseUrl(`http://localhost:64441/inventory`);
        });

        this.infrastructure = infrastructure;
    }
}
```

I have a couple of services that use `Infrastructure` like that and it all works fine.
The problem is that I no need to inject **two** such services onto the same class, and the configured `baseUrl` interfere with each other.

Everything is a singleton by default in Aurelia, I understand that, but what would be the preferred way to handle this situation in Aurelia?

I know I can always skip configuring the `baseUrl`, but it is quite handy to be able to configure and I'm curious if there's a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register multiple instances of the same "class" using different keys.  The registration key can be anything, it doesn't need to be a class/constructor-function.

Below is an example. First step is to change your `Infrastructure` class to accept a baseUrl argument in the constructor:

```js
export class Infrastructure {
  constructor(baseUrl) {
    this.configure(config => {
      config
        .useStandardConfiguration()
        .withBaseUrl(baseUrl);
      });
  }
  ...
}
```

Next you'll need to configure the container with the different `Infrastructure` instances. The code below would typically happen at startup, perhaps in the `main.js`:

```js
// configure the container
container.registerInstance("Inventory", new Infrastructure("http://foo.com"));
container.registerInstance("Orders", new Infrastructure("http://bar.com"));
```

Now you'll be able to resolve these instances by key:

```js
// resolve by name
var inventory = container.get("Inventory");
var orders = container.get("Orders");
```

Or declare them as dependencies using `@inject`:

```js
import {inject} from "aurelia-framework";

@inject("Inventory", "Orders")
export class InventoryService {
  constructor (inventory, orders) {
    this.inventory = inventory;
    this.orders = orders;
  }
}
```

There's a lot of discussion about a scenario much like yours in this issue:
https://github.com/aurelia/dependency-injection/issues/73

Comment: Thanks for you answer @Jeremy, but won't calling `.withBaseUrl("...")` on the underlying `HttpClient` still interfere int the two different instances, since `Infrastructure` is injecting the `HttpClient`? 
Also, am I doing something really bone-headed by inheriting from `HttpClient`?

Comment: updated answer- you may want to discontinue using an Infrastructure class that extends the HttpClient and use the HttpClient directly.

Comment: @Jeremy: Are there any downsides in deriving from HttpClient? Wouldn't the direct use of HttpClient prevent the use-case the OP was asking for, as in extending it with abstracted queries like delete or post? In addition: For future reference could you add the code for getting the aurelia-container-instance in your answer, as you've done [here](https://github.com/aurelia/dependency-injection/issues/73)?